# Eclipse block coloring

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm wondering if anyone can assist with a query I am having about Eclipse. I have used JDeveloper extensively for work and have enjoyed the 'block coloring' feature it has, whereby it can colour the background of methods and syntax blocks which I have found very helpful in deciphering some of the horrific legacy code we have.

To clarify what I mean, if I write a try catch finally block, the first line of the try until its closing brace are light blue, with the catch/finally a darker shade of blue. Similar with if/else statements (green/darker green), while loops (pink), etc. I have been playing with the EditBox plugin, however this is a different way of highlighting, which I don't find as clear as each statement/method type having its own colour.

If anyone can shed some light on this or point me towards options/plugins etc I would be very grateful.

S

Comment: Cheers for the answers everyone, bit sad that an equivalent feature is not available. Will have to make do with what I can.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing, but several other features which might help you identifying blocks more easily:

- If the cursor is directly before or after a brace or bracket, the other opening/closing brace or bracket is highlighted using a small rectangle around the character.
- If you double click in the empty space of the same line after an opening curly brace, then the content between the opening and closing brace is selected.
- If the cursor is on keywords like "break" or "return", their "related block" is highlighted, i.e. the "for" keyword around the break, or the function declaration around the return statement. This requires "Mark occurrences" to be active (should be available in your toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

For eclipse there is a plugin in alpha stage that offers a crude block coloring similar to JDev.
Please find the EditBox [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editbox#group-screenshots%20%22EditBox)

[image]